# Anaconda: conda update all conflict

Tags: python-2.7, zsh, anaconda, oh-my-zsh

The information about current `conda` installation is as below:

```
         platform : osx-64
    conda version : 4.1.5
conda-env version : 2.5.1
conda-build version : 0+unknown
   python version : 2.7.12.final.0
 requests version : 2.9.1
 root environment : /Users/chintanshah/anaconda  (writable)
default environment : /Users/chintanshah/anaconda
 envs directories : /Users/chintanshah/anaconda/envs
    package cache : /Users/chintanshah/anaconda/pkgs
     channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/
                    https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                    https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/
                    https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
      config file : None
     offline mode : False
is foreign system : False
```

When I try `conda update --all` I get the following message:

```
Fetching package metadata .......
Solving package specifications: ....

The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- bottleneck -> numpy 1.10*|1.11*|1.9*
- bottleneck -> python 3.4*|3.5*
- sockjs-tornado
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

It seems I need to reinstall Anaconda but I do not want to mess it up. Also, I am currently using `ZSH` instead of `bash`.

What would be the best to resolve this?

**EDIT:**

Yesterday, I installed the following:

```
pip install Plotly
pip install keras
conda install opencv
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: This is the closest I could get https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are still looking, this fixed it for me.

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when I try

```
$ conda install python=<new version>
```

My solution is to uninstall as many packages as possible first , then try the above command again.

The rational here is that the dependencies among packages are so complicated that conda cannot handle them in such a big update. Having minimum amount of packages will make conda's life easier.